# Java ObjectMapper Causes StackOverflow Infinite Loop Exceptipn

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am getting an infinite loop stack overflow and I am having trouble determining what the issue is that is causing it.  Here is part of the stack trace (because it just keeps repeating)

Note some code and stack trace removed because it is greater than allowed characters.

```
2023-04-07 10:33:07.446 ERROR 53488 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] c.s.c.c.e.tools.support.ModelMapper      : Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl["decl"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter[0]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["annotatedType"]->sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl["decl"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter[0]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["annotatedType"]->sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl["decl"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter[0]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["annotatedType"]-
...
>java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter[0]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["annotatedType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:789) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:253) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:214) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:23) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:253) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:214) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:23) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[cst-exodus-tools-1.0.0.jar:na]
```

Here is the object mapper wrapper class that I created that is throwing this error (officially is when the object mapper write is executed not this code but provided in case there is something broke here)

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ModelMapper {


    public static <T> T fromString(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        return ModelMapper.convertJsonToObjectString(json, clazz);
    }

    public static ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        mapper.registerModule(new CustomSimpleModule());
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        return mapper;
    }

    public static String toString(Object obj) {
        return ModelMapper.convertObjectToJsonString(obj);
    }

    private static <T> T convertJsonToObjectString(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        T returnValue = null;
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(json)) {
            try {
                returnValue = ModelMapper.getMapper().readValue(json, clazz);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                log.error(ignored.getMessage(), ignored);
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static String convertObjectToJsonString(Object obj) {
        String returnValue = null;
        if (Optional.ofNullable(obj).isPresent()) {
            try {
                returnValue = ModelMapper.getMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                log.error(ignored.getMessage(), ignored);
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

And this is the object that when has data is throwing the exception:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "UnusedReturnValue" })
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@With
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDetails implements Serializable {

    public static final String RESPONSE_BODY_KEY = "Response_Body";
    public static final String REQUEST_BODY_KEY = "Request_Body";
    public static final String REQUEST_HEADER_KEY = "Request_Header";
    public static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_KEY = "Response_Header";
    public static final String ADDITIONAL_FIELDS_KEY = "Additional Fields";
    public static final String STATUS_KEY = "status";
    public static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ExodusDateAndTimePatterns.DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE;
    public static final String ERROR_STATUS = "ErrorStatus";
    public static final String ERROR_TIMESTAMP = "ErrorTimestamp";
    public static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "ErrorMessage";
    public static final String ERROR_DEBUG_MESSAGE = "ErrorDebugMessage";
    public static final String ERROR_TYPE = "ErrorType";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3135141341712621098L;
    private boolean doNotLog;
    private boolean secureData;
    private Boolean external;
    private ResultsTraceLevel traceLevel;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private Class clazz;
    private String correlationId;
    private AdditionalProperties additionalProperties;
    private ExceptionDetails exceptionDetails;
    private HeaderType headerType;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;

    public static ErrorDetails getInstance() {
        ErrorDetails details = new ErrorDetails();
        details.setTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        details.addStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        details.addTraceLevelData(ResultsTraceLevel.ERROR);
        return details;
    }

    public AdditionalProperties getAdditionalProperties() {
        additionalProperties = Optional.ofNullable(additionalProperties).orElse(AdditionalProperties.getInstance());
        return additionalProperties;
    }

    public Object getAdditionalProperty(String key) {
        additionalProperties = Optional.ofNullable(additionalProperties).orElse(AdditionalProperties.getInstance());
        return additionalProperties.getAdditionalProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Here is example of the data in the object when it is throwing the exception.

```
ErrorDetails(doNotLog=false,
 secureData=false,
 external=null,
 traceLevel=null,
 status=400 BAD_REQUEST,
 message=Required request header 'Nuance-Session-ID' for method parameter type String is not present,
 clazz=null,
 correlationId=null,
 additionalProperties=AdditionalProperties(properties={Exception=ExceptionDetails(name=org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException,
 message=Required request header 'Nuance-Session-ID' for method parameter type String is not present,
 methodName=wrapRequestWithLogging,
 lineNumber=HttpInboundLoggingSpringWebFilter.java:155,
 rootCause=null),
 Headers={Content-Type=application/json,
 accept-encoding=gzip,
 deflate,
 br,
 connection=keep-alive,
 host=localhost:8443,
 postman-token=beccc42e-9c48-4573-840b-20dd65a70913,
 user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.31.3},
 MissingParameter=method 'getProfiles' parameter 2,
 Request=ServletWebRequest: uri=/MoneyLink/MLGetRequestList;client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
 Request Parameters=org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap@50d193b7}),
 exceptionDetails=ExceptionDetails(name=org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException,
 message=Required request header 'Nuance-Session-ID' for method parameter type String is not present,
 methodName=wrapRequestWithLogging,
 lineNumber=HttpInboundLoggingSpringWebFilter.java:155,
 rootCause=null),
 header=Header(accept=null,
 authorization=null,
 contentType=application/json,
 nvpSessionId=null,
 nuanceSessionId=null,
 sessionId=null,
 headerType=null,
 additionalProperties=AdditionalProperties(properties={accept-encoding=gzip,
 deflate,
 br,
 connection=keep-alive,
 host=localhost:8443,
 postman-token=beccc42e-9c48-4573-840b-20dd65a70913,
 user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.31.3})),
 headerType=null,
 timeStamp=null)
```

Note that if the object is empty (I just create an instance and try to convert) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i tested with my JsonUtils and it works just fine, try to test it with this

```
public class JsonUtils {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .findAndAddModules()
            .build();
    public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<? extends T> type) {

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error parsing json, message[{}]", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

ps: i needed to modify some fields for making mapper to ignore when null was passed, use `@JsonIgnore` for ignoring and `@JsonProperty` for naming fields with symbols like '-'

Comment: It is technically the write to string that fails.  Using the methods above.  I am wondering if my setup for ObjectMapper is messing it up somehow.

Comment: I use the same method to convert the object to JSON, but I do not have the same configuration for the mapper instead I just have `findAndAddModules()`, probably one or more of your mapper configurations may be the cause